What was the problem Hilbert mentioned in his student's funeral?
I've seen this anecdote many times now. Does anybody knows the full statement of the very interesting problem Hilbert was talking about?


I expect the story is apocryphal...in any case, the version I have heard claims that it concerned one part of a proposed program to prove the Riemann Hypothesis.

To me, this story seems unlikely to be true. It is a joke, after all.

Well, even if it is the punchline of a classic math joke, then that is very interesting as well, I think. +1

What's the book? (I would like to know!) Actually, it would probably be a good idea to include that in the original post.

@peterag: https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Apocrypha-Anecdotes-Mathematicians-Spectrum/dp/0883855399/

@HansLundmark thank you!

This story appears in Constance Reid's biography of Hilbert (page 163). It is, however, emphasized as possibly apocryphal and if there was substantive evidence Reid does not indicate such.


To pursue this further, one would probably want to go beyond Reid's English-language biography and look into biographies of Hilbert in German. But that's beyond my expertise.
